# Sublime, SASS exclude with regex?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have the OnSaveBuild plugin with this setting:

```
"filename_filter": "\\.(css|js|sass|less|scss)$"
```

which will compile those formats on save. However, in the case of sass/scss, I want to exclude the imported files starting with "_". How can I alter this option to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think this should do what you want. I assume the file name (before the extension part) contains at least one character, for the case of `sass` and `scss`.

```
"^[^_].*\\.(sass|scss)$|\\.(css|js|less)$"
```

Comment: This should work, but I have a feeling it's a problem with the plugin for not accepting it.

Comment: @Brian: It only uses very basic regex syntax. If this is not going to work, then neither is yours.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

```
"filename_filter": "(/|\\\\|^)(?!_)(\\w+)\\.(css|js|sass|less|scss)$",
```

Found here: https://github.com/alexnj/SublimeOnSaveBuild/issues/11#issuecomment-24952435